# Airflow RabbitMQ sensor

Tags: rabbitmq, airflow, amqp

Is there an airflow sensor that exists that subscribes to a message in a RabbitMQ queue?

I noticed that there is a [PubSub sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/pubsub.html) that accomplishes that is similar to what I want.

I could accomplish this quite easily using a PythonOperator, but I find it strange that a RabbitMQ sensor doesn't already exist.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no - you don't miss anything. Airflow is an open-source project that has almost 1800 contributors. And likely none of them contributed RabbitMQ sensor yet.

Which is a great opportunity for you - how about creating a new provider and contributing a RabbitMQ sensor there?

Happy to help and review the PR!

Comment: Thanks Jarek, I think I will do that! I have begun by looking at the Google PubSub code for an idea of where to start. Are there any reference guides you could recommend for writing custom sensors? Particularly interested in writing good tests (preferably using pytest, but I'm not fussy)

Comment: Just take a look at the examples in the code - we have PLENTY of them - a lot of sensors and all of them are automatically tested with pytest :D:

Comment: Here is guide on how to create a new `community` provider (which you'd have to start with) https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/howto/create-update-providers.html

Comment: That should give you a good start, and from there taking a look at the other provider's code is best. The Google Operators/Hooks (including PubSub) are pretty good to start with - they usually follow all the good practices. And we do not accept a code without tests - so you might be sure the tests are there :D

Comment: Hi Jarek, we have now developed [airflow-provider-rabbitmq](https://github.com/tes/airflow-provider-rabbitmq). It is quite simple atm and fits our project needs. Would be interested in hearing what work would be needed to make it acceptable as a community provider :)

Comment: Easy: Follow this - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/howto/create-update-providers.html

Comment: Hi @SoftwareThings, your link is broken, can you post a new link please?